# C++ program .exe stopped working

Tags: c++

I can't understand why my program getting stopped, and I can't find a mistake... I tried some changes but still I can't understand.. And displays only one line but it should be more than one...

The code:

```
void findcomm () {
    char det = '**';
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        string str (lines[i]);
        vector<char> k (str.begin(), str.end());
        vector<size_t>positions;
        size_t pos = str.find (det, 0);
        while (pos != string::npos) {
            positions.push_back (pos);
            pos = str.find (det, pos+1);
        }
        vector<char> c;
        for (int g = positions[0]+2; g < positions.back()-1; g++) {
            c.push_back (k[g]);
        }
        string comm (c.begin(), c.end());
        cout << comm << "\n";
        comments.push_back (comm);
        c.clear ();
        k.clear ();
        positions.clear ();
    }
}
```

I tried to remove this piece of code and then "program has stopped" disappeared, so I think the problem is here. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Multi-length characters: `char det = '**';` are non-standard so from this point on you need to refer to your compiler manual.

Comment: *I tried to remove this piece of code and then "program has stopped" disappeared --  tried some changes but still I can't understand..* -- Trial and error is not a good way to learn a computer language such as C++.

Comment: Can you elaborate little more what exactly you are trying to achieve here?  What is lines and what value it contains etc.?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BDML52Fi there's the full code

Comment: I believe the site that you're looking for @AlexP. is https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `char det = '**';` This doesn't do what you probably think it does, so start by fixing this line. In other news, global variables are bad and should be avoided.

Comment: The linked code is broken in many interestng ways. It looks like you need a different C++ book, or prrhaps some C++ book.

Answer (score 0):

try using `getch()` between line or trace code 
this would help you to find when it exits.also use exception handling techinics

replace

```
det="**"
```

---

with `det[]={"**"};`

Comment: Since this is C++, prefer `std::string det = "**";` rather than character arrays.

Comment: did you trace the code. some may have garbage value that cause run time error

Comment: @ThomasMatthews There nothing wrong with a caracter array, but I do agree that a `std::string_view` would be even better than a string or a character array.